# 1) SQL server external activation: cluster aware? 2) source code available?

Tags: sql-server, cluster-computing

We have been using SSBEA for a number of years. However, we've observed odd behavior in a SQL server clustered environment. When in failover mode (node 2) The configured server named does not work, we are forced to use an alias (ironically alias does not work in node 1-primary) and reconfigure the service; However it does indeed work in the executable (handler) that receives the dispatched message... its configuration does NOT have to change in failover mode. So, this seems to be that SSBEA is not cluster aware.
Has anyone experienced this? Or, is anyone running SSBEA in a clustered environment and no config changes need to take place when failing over?

Also, is the source code available? Perhaps a different driver needs to be used. We would like more control over the logging (location, for example); currently it's limited.

Thank you

Comment: I don't have experience with SSBEA in a clustered environment specifically, but so long as you're using the cluster name (as opposed to the name of the node currently hosting the FCI), I'd expect it to work. What is the behavior when you do the failover? An error? Or does it silently stop receiving messages?

Comment: Unfortunately, it DOES not work. Nothing, no messages doesn't recognize the server name